# Split a pandas dataframe by a list of values from another data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm pretty sure there's a really simple solution for this and I'm just not realising it. However...

I have a data frame of high-frequency data. Call this data frame A. I also have a separate list of far lower frequency demarcation points, call this B. I would like to append a column to A that would display 1 if A's timestamp column is between B[0] and B[1], 2 if it is between B[1] and B[2], and so on.

As said, it's probably incredibly trivial, and I'm just not realising it at this late an hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty approach using a list comprehension.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.arange(1, 3, 0.2)})

>>> A = df.A.values.tolist()
A: [1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2.0, 2.2, 2.5, 2.6, 2.8]

>>> B = np.arange(0, 3, 1).tolist()
B: [0, 1, 2]

>>> BA = [k for k in range(0, len(B)-1) for a in A if (B[k]<=a) & (B[k+1]>a) or (a>max(B))]
BA: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`searchsorted`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html):

```
A['group'] = B['timestamp'].searchsorted(A['timestamp'])
```

For each value in `A['timestamp']`, an index value is returned. That index indicates where amongst the sorted values in `B['timestamp']` that value from `A` would be inserted into `B` in order to maintain sorted order.

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2016)

N = 10
A = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=N).cumsum()})
B = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':np.random.uniform(0, 3, size=N).cumsum()})
#    timestamp
# 0   1.739869
# 1   2.467790
# 2   2.863659
# 3   3.295505
# 4   5.106419
# 5   6.872791
# 6   7.080834
# 7   9.909320
# 8  11.027117
# 9  12.383085

A['group'] = B['timestamp'].searchsorted(A['timestamp'])
print(A)
```

yields

```
   timestamp  group
0   0.896705      0
1   1.626945      0
2   2.410220      1
3   3.151872      3
4   3.613962      4
5   4.256528      4
6   4.481392      4
7   5.189938      5
8   5.937064      5
9   6.562172      5
```

Thus, the timestamp `0.896705` is in group `0` because it comes before `B['timestamp'][0]` (i.e. `1.739869`). The timestamp `2.410220` is in group `1` because it is larger than `B['timestamp'][0]` (i.e. `1.739869`) but smaller than `B['timestamp'][1]` (i.e. `2.467790`).

---

You should also decide what to do if a value in `A['timestamp']` is exactly equal to one of the cutoff values in `B['timestamp']`. Use

```
B['timestamp'].searchsorted(A['timestamp'], side='left')
```

if you want searchsorted to return `i` when `B['timestamp'][i] <= A['timestamp'][i] <= B['timestamp'][i+1]`. Use

```
B['timestamp'].searchsorted(A['timestamp'], side='right')
```

if you want searchsorted to return `i+1` in that situation. If you don't specify `side`, then `side='left'` is used by default.